# Symfony best practice - using Materialize CSS Chips with Symfony Forms

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony, materialize

I've begun a project in Symfony 3 which needs to allow users to create a post with some data, and a collection of tags (many-to-many). The CSS framework I've been using is MaterializeCSS and there's a [handy class](http://materializecss.com/chips.html) called 'chips' which would be nice to allow input for the tags.

I've been using the Form objects as per the Symfony guide with no issues so far, however my issue is that the materialize CSS constructs its 'Chips' field like this:

```
  <div class="chips"></div>

...

  $('.chips').material_chip();
```

I can't for the life of me see how to do this inside of a Symfony form, or how to retrieve the data after submission if done with custom form rendering. I could just not use it, but the UX would suffer. I've read a bit about the `CollectionType` class inside of Symfony but I'm still not sure that this would be appropriate to use with chips.

I'm sure somebody's completed a project like this before, would be great to have some input. All help appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to add a hidden input and chip to handle the issue check this http://jsbin.com/yoxupumapo/edit?html,console,output

Comment: This worked perfectly, and just required an override of how the form is handled on the other side. If you want to submit this as an answer below I'll accept it (so you get the proper credit), otherwise I can just answer the q myself and cite your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed above , the idea is to have some glue js code to manipulate a hidden field which contains tags as comma separated values and bind the chip widget with that hidden field as data source and target e.g

Desired html

```
  Input field(might be hidden):
  <input name="chips" value="Apple,Hello,World">

  The Chip:
  <div class="chips"/>
```

Glue js

```
<script>
     function updateChipInput(chip){
       var newval= $(chip).material_chip('data')
          .reduce(function(result,val){ result.push(val.tag); return result;},[]).join(",")

       $('input[name="chips"]').val(newval);
     }

    $(document).ready(function(){
     var data= $('input[name="chips"]').val().split(',') 
       .map(function(tag){
         return {tag:tag}
       })

     $('.chips').material_chip({
       data: data          
    });

     $('.chips').on('chip.add', function(e, chip){
       updateChipInput(this);
    })
     .on('chip.delete', function(e, chip){
       updateChipInput(this);
    });  
   });
  </script>
```

[working demo](http://jsbin.com/yoxupumapo/edit?html,console,output)

The input is text field to show the effects in example you can set its type to hidden ,thanks

Comment: what's the proper way to implement this materialize chip version through a custom formtype ? can we base it on a choice/entity type ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try something like this ?

```
{{ form(form.name, { 'attr': {'class': 'chips'} }) }}
```

I recommend you to read this [post](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html)

Comment: Yes, sorry. My understanding is that form customisation is based off of adding attributes to `<input />` tags, whereas Materialize's Chips is not based off of an input, but a `<div>`.

I've customised a lot of the other forms in the site, but it seems like Materialize's chips are a different animal.

Comment: If not you can try to make the forms without symfony forms , just make them in html and use JavaScript or any Js framework to send requests to php , this way is more user friendly because you don't need to load all the page .